# Event in jQuery .html() won't detect

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, selector

I'm trying to use a button that is printed by .html(). I've tried .find() after searching through this site but the onclick event still seem not detected.

```
<div id = "div4html">div</div>
<button id="printbtn">printbtn</button>

<script>
$("#printbtn").on( "click", function() {
    $("#div4html").html('<button id ="btntest">btntest</button>');
});

$("#div4html").find("#btntest").on( "click", function() { 
    alert("on click");
});
</script>
```

while the #btntest onclick doesn't show an alert, the CSS on #btntest works.
There is something I don't know about elements that are created dynamically?

Comment: Learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) i.e. `$("#div4html").on( "click", "#btntest", function() { `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:-`$("#div4html").on( "click", "#btntest", function() {`

It's called:-  [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Example:-

```js
$("#printbtn").on( "click", function() {
  $("#div4html").html('<button id ="btntest">btntest</button>');
});

$("#div4html").on( "click","#btntest", function() { 
  alert("on click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div4html">div</div><br>
<button id="printbtn">printbtn</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because js don't even for events in newly created content by default.

Here is the way to do it :

```
$("#div4html").on('click', "#btntest" , function() {
// Your code
}
```

Comment: Seems identical to mine.but correct so +1

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event from the body

```
$("body").on( "click",'#btntest', function() { 
   alert("on click");
});
```

Comment: Instead of delegate through body it's best to delegate through parent itself. less traversal, fast and correct approach.